# Uniform convergence of the sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, riemann-integration

Let $f$ be defined on $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ and $$S(f) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(\frac{k}{n})$$Assume that $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of functions such that for every $n$, $S(f_n)$ exists. If $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $\mathbb{Q}$, prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}S(f_n)$$ exists and $S(f_n) \to S(f)$.

**My try:** I don't know how to deal with $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ because it has zero measure and the summation is the Riemann sum, $$S(f) = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$$ Also is the first $f$, which is defined on $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$, same as the second $f$? I'm confused about this because I think the second $f$ should be defined on $\mathbb{Q}$ in order to "$f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $\mathbb{Q}$" has meaning.

**Edit:** I'm taking my first real analysis course and I'm not familiar with Equidistributed sequence and Weyl's ergodic theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result follows from the inequality

$$\left\vert \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(\frac{k}{n})-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f_m(\frac{k}{n})\right\vert \le \Vert f - f_m\Vert_\infty$$ valid for any $n, m \in \mathbb N$ which implies
$$\vert S(f) -S(f_m)\vert \le \Vert f - f_m \Vert _\infty$$ for all $m \in \mathbb N$.

*Note: no need to use integration here.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would explain about this inequality and the conditions under which it holds? In addition, I'm still confused about the domain of $f$.

Comment: You just need $f$ and the $f_m$ to be defined on $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$, which is the case. The inequality is an immediate consequence of triangular inequality for a finite number of reals.

Comment: I see. So by $\Vert f \Vert _\infty$ you mean $\sup\{|f(x)| : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$, right?

Comment: Yes. This is a classical notation. Here, I mean the $\sup$ on $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$, which is a sufficient domain for our functions.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've asked a related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4169106/uniform-convergence-and-triangle-inequality) to your answer. I would be grateful if you could take a look.